# Application stopped working after some time

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, http-post

I'm experiencing weird problem. I'm new to android, I've coded some random app that sends some data to my external database. Everything was working properly and few days ago it stopped. It wouldn't be anything special but...I've done 0 changes, I wasn't touching the code. It just stopped working for no reason. Here's a part of my (i know, bad) code. I'm getting `NullPointerEx` on **client.execute(hp)** line (if I understood logcat well).

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    double longitude = loc.getLongitude();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoggedInSys.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    String username = editText.getText().toString();

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost hp = new HttpPost("LINK TO MY PHP SCRIPT");
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(latitude)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", String.valueOf(longitude)));            
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", username));                   
        hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(hp);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();


    }catch(Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    try {
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        isr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    result = sb.toString();


    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(latitude));
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(longitude));

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME, username);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVID, result);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It's really strange, how could it stop working when I didn't change anything? Any suggestions please?

**Log:**

```
 11-13 10:42:52.689: D/AndroidRuntime(26259): Shutting down VM
11-13 10:42:52.689: W/dalvikvm(26259): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2168)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2163)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    ... 11 more
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    at com.example.mojaapka.MainActivity.logInSystem(MainActivity.java:61)
11-13 10:42:52.689: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):    ... 14 more
11-13 10:42:54.539: I/Process(26259): Sending signal. PID: 26259 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Kindly post your logcat

Comment: I think you're actually doing networking on UI thread and that crashes your code. You should use an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Well, but it was working like a week or 2 weeks ago. That's strange for me. Added log

Comment: @user2987001 what is line 61 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @Raghunandan it's: HttpResponse response = client.execute(hp); I guess

Comment: @user2987001 cross check again are you sure that is the line that causes NPE?

Comment: @Raghunandan yea it is this one.

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm really sorry - my mistake - it's line: double latitude = loc.getLatitude();

Comment: @user2987001 then you need to make sure its not null. check if `loc` is null

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes thanks, but now I've got another problem: LocationManager (and Listener in next activity also) appear to be not working, any idea why? As I said, it was working, can it be any hardware issue? (I'm using real device)